# Dagger 2 no classes generated

Tags: java, maven, dagger, dagger-2

I want to try something new and use Dagger 2 as my DI framework. So I have the following pom and the "hello world" coffee maker classes (http://google.github.io/dagger/) in my projekt.

But when I do a mvn clean install no classes get generated. As far as I unterstood there should be a "Dagger_CoffeeShop" class generated. Hmmm ... what am I missing?

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>kic</groupId>
<artifactId>xfoo</artifactId>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case I downloaded the JAR files directly since I don't believe they were published to maven central yet.  I was assuming I need to compile it first, then add the line: Coffee coffee = Dagger_CoffeeApp$Coffee.builder().build().  But Dagger_CoffeeApp is never generated. I had no issues with Dagger 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those using Gradle: Make sure you are referencing the Dagger dependencies as following:

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
```

And in the case if you are running into `apt` not supported, add

1) Into module `app\build.gradle`:

`apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'`

2) Into project `\build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer.  Cause seriously, who isn't taking advantage of Gradle.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, only with the release version 2.0.

In my case the following two steps solved this problem:

- Adding `target/generated-sources/annotations` to my build path
- Adding `<forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>` to the maven compiler plugin

  ```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <!-- workaround for https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-202 -->
            <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  ```

See also:

- https://github.com/google/dagger/pull/103
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-202

Comment: @LucianoBrum Yes it does. Of course you need to use `<release>11</release>` instead of the `<source>` and `<target>` versions. Also you'd most likely want use newer versions of the compiler plugin as well as dagger. The aforementioned workaround is no longer needed for the latest maven-complier plugin.

If you just copy-pasted this snippet, it won't work.

Comment: I have already tried many things, dagger 2.x is not working with maven and java 11. I will create a minimal example and share it.

Comment: I use Dagger with Java 11+ all the time and can confirm it works as expected. I suspect you have some different problem. Also the original post is specifically about Java 8, so I would suggest you create a new thread.

Comment: You were right. The problem was trivial. Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66216082/using-dagger-with-java-11-and-maven

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best answer. When I used the downloaded JAR files (commented out in the POM file below) mine also wasn't generating the Dagger_ files. Once I added the repository to the POM, everything was working fine.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.hello</groupId>
  <artifactId>hellodagger</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>hellodagger</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype</id>
      <name>sonatype-repo</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <!--<scope>system</scope>-->
        <!--<systemPath>${project.basedir}/dagger-2.0-20141216.223138-12.jar</systemPath>-->
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <!--<scope>system</scope>-->
        <!--<systemPath>${project.basedir}/dagger-compiler-2.0-20141216.223201-12-jar-with-dependencies.jar</systemPath>-->
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```