# Using Dagger with java 11 and maven

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, dagger-2, java-11

Does Google Dagger DIF works with java 11?

If not, what is the alternative, given that changing the project to use java 8 is not possible.

Comment: Probably not. That is unfortunate. Sounds like you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Dagger2 is totally ok with java 11 i'm using it on a project with gradle without probleme. 
I don't know about maven but i think it's okay too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use dagger 2.32 with maven and java 11.

I was having issues with compilation process and eclipse environment.

Eclipse was showing errors saying that DaggerMyClassComponent was not found. DaggerMyClassComponent is a generated class from MyClassComponent with @Component annotation from Dagger. This class (and others) is generated when we do 'mvn clean compile' command. Before that, eclipse will show errors.

Also, if you run 'Maven -> Update Project', eclipse will fix the problem (it will run compile phase from maven). You can check generated classes in /target/generated-sources/annotation folder.

Also, while developing with dagger and eclipse, errors may appear if you change classes annotated with @Components and @Modules. Running 'mvn clean' solves the errors related with generated classes from Dagger, because this command erases the /target folder content (including old generated classes from dagger).