# Is hilt not available in java 11 in android project?

Tags: java, android, dagger-hilt

Is hilt not available in java 11 in android project?

In the Android official documentation, it is set as follows.

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

If the project is migrated to use java 11, can't I use hilt?

Comment: As https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66216082 explains, `hilt` will work with Java 11.

Comment: Also, see https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/3207